# Why does light ray not change direction when it pass though the curve part of the semi-circular glass block?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

[image: .]

Why does light ray not change direction when it pass through the semi circle part of the block but when it pass through the flat edge of the glass block it change direction.

Comment: Draw the tangent line on that point of the circle and see what the refraction angles should be.

Comment: -1. Why do you expect it to change direction? What do you expect the angle of refraction to be?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Because in the left-hand case the incoming ray is perpendicular to the surface so it is not refracted. In other words the angle of incidence is zero in contrast to the right-hand case.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a very special light ray, that travels radially from the centre of the semicircle. This light ray will hit the semicircle edge at a right angle causing no refraction.